# Pictures to words

Tags: knowledge

There are three set of images, for each set please determine a word/phrase representing it, and determine the final word by the three words/phrases. (A set can have any amount of images.)

Set 1:

> [image: 1]]

Set 2:

> [image: 2]
>
> [image: 3]
>
> [image: 4]

Set 3:

> [image: 5]

Ok, you probably won't need to think for set three, but in set one, you have to think for a while, and for set two and final word, you have to have some knowledge.

Tips 0

> The answer to set three is "f___ m___", in case you want to check.

Tips 1 (50 viewers)

> The answer to set one is "S_____".

Tips 2 (100 viewers)

> The answer to set one is "Sun___".

Tips 3 (200 viewers)

> Look at set 1, the image is a sun in a day.

Comment: Fhcre Cvax Zbba?

Comment: @ManojKumar What?

Comment: @CulverKwan He/She probably means rot13(Fhcre Cvax Zbba)?

Comment: @ManojKumar You are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I believe that:

Set 1 is

> **Sunday**. A big picture of a sun, and it is during the day

Set 2 is

> **The March equinox**. We have another picture of the Sun, and the equator. I guess that the focal point A refers to the zero point of sidereal time: the March equinox being the zero point of sidereal time

Set 3 is

> **Full moon**. This answer was all but provided in the hints

Putting these 3 sets together, very clearly gives us the word

> Easter.
>  Easter is traditionally celebrated on the first **Sunday** after the first **full moon** following the **March equinox**.

Comment: shouldn't that be rot13(Ireany Rdhvabk)?

Comment: @DavidG. Only in the northern hemisphere

Comment: Correct! You will get the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> Set 1: Sunday 
>  Set 2: Sundial 
>  Set 3: Full Moon

Final answer:

> A watch?

Explanation:

> Sun in a day -> Sunday 
>  Because of the pole in the middle, so a sundial? 
>  Full Moon 
>  
>  A watch can show you what day it is (Sunday), what time it is (Sundial), and some high-tech watches can show you when is the next **Full Moon**

Comment: Second set incorrect. I will post more tips later.